# How to disable the radio button using javascript ? (Not using any JS framework)

Tags: javascript, html

For example I have html elements like

```
<input type="radio" name="disableme" id=1> Animal
<input type="radio" name="disableme" id=2> Mammal
<input type="radio" name="disableme" id=3> Human
```

I tried like , `document.formName.disableme.disabled = true;` But it didn't worked..

I can do it using Id. But I need it in one shot.

Please help.

Comment: You can use id instead of name or you can get documentgetElementbyName  and store in javascript variable and check it using for loop

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> I tried like , document.formName.disableme.disabled = true; But it didn't worked..

Because if you have more than one form control with the same name, you will get back an [HTML Form Controls Collection](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#htmlformcontrolscollection). So loop over the collection:

```
var radios = document.formName.disableme;

for (var i=0, iLen=radios.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  radios[i].disabled = true;
}
```

There is no need to add an ID.

Comment: WAW .. This is what I want .. Thanks you.. Will accept your answer after 5 mins ..:)

Comment: Very helpful. This solved my problem too. I didn't know about those collections. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8):

```
document.getElementById("1").disabled=true;
document.getElementById("2").disabled=true;
document.getElementById("3").disabled=true;
```

Comment: For some reason getElementById did not work in my case. Hence, I just did it using `document.formName` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/57819100/4266332

Answer (score 5):

Try this code

```
var radio=document.getElementsByName("disableme");
   var len=radio.length;
   for(var i=0;i<len;i++)
   {
       radio[i].disabled=true;
   }


<input type="radio" name="disableme" id=1> Animal
<input type="radio" name="disableme"  id=2> Mammal
<input type="radio" name="disableme"  disabled="disabled" id=3> Human
```

Answer (score 4):

first of all your ids should be given in double quote.
like this:

```
 <input type="radio" name="disableme" id="1"> Animal
 <input type="radio" name="disableme" id="2"> Mammal
 <input type="radio" name="disableme" id="3"> Human
```

and for disabling the button using javascript,use this:

```
document.getElementById("1").disabled=true;
```

Comment: More importantly, an ID can't start with a number.

Comment: The quotes are unnecessary, and browsers have no problem with numeric ids (the HTML 4.01 spec has, but the restriction is being lifted in HTML5).

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it in one shot.

You have three separate elements, so you have to disable them one at a time. There is no way using plain Javascript to disable all three elements at once.

`document.formName.disableme` returns an array, so you can't access element properties on that, but you can loop through the elements and access properties on each element:

```
var radios = document.formName.disableme;
for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
  radios[i].disabled = true;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/2uUKw/

Comment: @Sahal: Hm... The reference "above answer" doesn't work, as the answers doesn't have a fixed order...

Comment: After you edit I understood ... 'You have three separate elements, so you have to disable them one at a time' this make sense :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use only name attribute to disable it, then you could use

`document.getElementsByName("disableme")[0].disabled = true;`

Answer (score 0):

```
function disable()
{
    var rads = document.formname.disableme;

    for(var i=0; i<rads.length;i++ )
    {
        document.formname.disableme[i].disabled = true;
    } 
}
```

Comment: some explanation would help this answer

Comment: on which event you want disable radio group call this function.. This function gets all the radio elements corresponding to the radio group name and disables one by one

Answer (score -1):

This is the simplest way to do (even if you have same `id`) for radio button

**Radio button definition :**

```
<input type="radio" name="paymentType" id="paymentType" value="CASH" /> CASH
<input type="radio" name="paymentType" id="paymentType" value="CHEQUE" /> CHEQUE
<input type="radio" name="paymentType" id="paymentType" value="DD" /> DD
```

**Disabling all 3 values:**

```
    document.formName.paymentType[0].disabled = false;
    document.formName.paymentType[1].disabled = false;
    document.formName.paymentType[2].disabled = false;
    ...
```