# Remove radiobutton selection when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have set up a radio button which when clicked, enables a textbox that allows numbers from 1-100 through the use of a range validator.

When the confirm button is clicked when the number is greater than 100 the validation appears fine, however the radio button that enables the textbox is still checked.

Is there a way to reset/clear the radio button when the validation occurs? Like through javascript perhaps?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Does this answer your question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13245672/how-to-disable-the-radio-button-using-javascript-not-using-any-js-framework

Comment: You have to uncheck it => $('radio').prop('checked', false);

Comment: @FrédéricGRATI, question is not tagged with jQuery

Comment: Sure, there are quite a lot of ways. What have you tried?

Comment: @Luketep I dont think that will work considering I need to only reset it after validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using Code Behind Prefer This `RadioButton1.checked = false` , In case of Java Script use `document.getElementById("RadioButton1").checked = false` and perform function call at button `OnClientClick()` event.

Comment: I used the code behind method and it worked! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/h_awk/rYv9m/

i have created a fiddle over here, please see the below code and run it on the fiddle.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        </script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

        <style type="text/css">
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form id="form1">
            <input type="radio" name="1" class="radio" />Test<br />
            <input type="radio" name="1" class="radio" />Testt<br />
        </form>

        <button id="submit">Button</button>

        <script>
            var submit = document.getElementById('submit');
            var radio = document.getElementsByClassName('radio');

            function uncheck()
            {
                if( radio[0].checked || radio[1].checked )
                {
                    radio[0].checked = false;
                    radio[1].checked = false;
                }
            }

            submit.addEventListener('click', uncheck, false);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..You can use javascript..

```
<asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server"  OnClientClick="abc();return false;"/>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
         function abc() {
             document.getElementById("RadioButton1").checked = false;
         }
       </script>
```